# Наилучший loc по 500 колонкам

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

https://www.kaggle.com/jingobox/filling-nan-based-on-the-patterns
В данном решении прописываем все 4 колонки вручную, а если колонок 500, то это будет затруднительно. Существует ли вариант сделать лок по множеству значений, а не прописывать каждый раз? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: вы можете уточнить суть вопроса? Что вы хотите сделать? Какой `loc`?

Comment: data.loc[(data['C1']==x.iloc[i,0]) & (data['C2']==x.iloc[i,1]) & (data['C13']==x.iloc[i,2]) & (data['C14']==x.iloc[i,3]) & (data[cols[q[0]]]==x.iloc[i,4]),cols[q[1]]]

Comment: то есть чтобы не с амперсандами мучаться а как-то проще

Comment: что такое `x`?? Вы можете описать словами в вопросе что вы пытаетесь сделать? Люди, которые захотят вам помочь не должны копаться в коде по ссылкам... ;) А еще лучше привести небольшие примеры входных и выходных данных...

Comment: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для более удобного фильтрования воспользуйтесь методом [DataFrame.query()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
c1_val = <>
c2_val = <>
qry="""C1 == @c1_val & C2 = @c2_val & ... & C14 == @c14_val"""

data.query(qry)
```

PS предвижу появление вопросов о том как пользоваться данным методом в вашем случае с использованием ваших данных и ваших переменных... Приведите в вопросе небольшой воспроизводимый пример входных данных, переменных для фильтрования и то, что вы хотите получить в результате ;)